# Haskell Monadic forms

Tags: haskell, monads

A simple question:
given the definitions, (From Haskell SOE)

```
   do x — el; el\ ...; en 
    => el »= \x — do e2\ ...; en
```

and:

```
do let decllist; el\...; en 
=> let decllist in do e2\ ...; en
```

it seems that these two constructs are the same:

```
do let x = e1
   e2
```

and

```
do x <- e1
   e2
```

both evaluate e1, bind it to e2, and then evaluate e2.

Yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do a simple example in the `Maybe` monad:

```
foo = do
        let x = Just 1
        return x
```

and

```
bar = do
        x <- Just 1
        return x
```

Desugaring both, we get

```
foo = let x = Just 1 in return x    -- do notation desugaring
    = return (Just 1)               -- let
    = Just (Just 1)                 -- definition of return for the Maybe monad

bar = let ok x = return x in Just 1 >>= ok   -- do notation desugaring
    = let ok x = return x in ok 1   -- definition of >>= for the Maybe monad
    = return 1                      -- definiton of ok
    = Just 1                        -- definition of return for the Maybe monad
```

For reference, I am using the [translation from section 3.14 of the Haskell 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same. For example,

```
do let x = getLine
   print x
```

translates to

```
let x = getLine in print x
```

this is a type error, as `x` will have the type `IO String`. We're asking to print the computation itself, not its result.

---

```
do x <- getLine
   print x
```

translates to

```
getLine >>= \x -> print x
```

Here `x` is bound as the result of the computation and its type is `String`, so this type checks.

---

In `do`-notation, `let` just binds values to names like it always does, while `<-` is used to perform monadic binding, which is binding a name to the *result* of a computation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `e1` is a computation of type `Monad m => m a`, then `let x = e1` and `x <- e1` mean somewhat different things.

In the `let`-version, when you use `x` within a do-expression, you are dealing with a value of type `Monad m => m a`.

In the other version, when you use `x` within a do expression, you are dealing with a value of type `a` (since do-notation implicitly handles mapping over the monad).

For example:

```
e :: IO Int
f :: Int -> Int

-- the following will result in a type error, since f operates on `Int`, not `IO Int`:
g = do let x = e
       return $ f x

-- the following will work:
g' = do x <- e
        return $ f x
```

Comment: Thanks. Monads remind me of Quantum mechanics - "if you think you understand them, you don't"! :-)

Comment: In my example;  e::Int, so the "let" would work, and not the arrow then - yes?

Comment: @Guthrie Oh, if `e :: Int`, then you do need to use `let`.

Answer (score 0):

No.  `x <- e1` translates to `e1 >>= \x ->`, an incomplete expression; the `let` expression is just a normal `let`.  Or are you asking if `let` and `(>>=)` are the same thing?  They very much aren't:  `(>>=)` exposes the thing wrapped by a monad to a function, which must produce something wrapped in the monad.  In other words, with `x <- e1`, `e1`'s type must be `IO a` for some `a`, but with `let x = e1` `e1`'s type is just `a`; in both cases the type of `x` will be `a`.

Comment: A `let` in a `do`-expression is not just a normal `let` expression.  It is a `let` statement (Haskell 2010 Report, section 3.14).  The `let` statement desugars into a `let` expression, but it is not in itself a `let` expression.   Likewise `e1 >>= \x ->` is meaningless.  It is better to just to look at the translation rules in the Report.